# videojs: play loop video without re-load

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

I'm using videojs to play a background loop video.

But when it's on ended, it reloading the video about 0.2s

How to play a loop video without delay?

my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wdaLq8pk/

```html
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.11/video.js"></script>
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.11/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<video id="video_page" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" loop autoplay width="683" height="384" preload="auto" data-setup='{}'>
  <source src="http://navademo.com/akva-group/uploads/videos/page_2_loop.ogv" type='video/ogg'>
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but I think it's because you're using more of an older style of html and styling for the code? HTML5 and CSS3 is how you want to approach this if I'm not mistaken.  The main thing you want to achieve here is to keep the CSS and HTML as separate as possible.  This worked for me but if you find yourself stuck, this is what I used as a reference guide: http://thenewcode.com/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0x5e.png)

1. I used this smooth-scroll.js file and put it in the directory where I usually put in my jQuery files.

   ```
   $(function () {
     $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function () {
       if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
         var target = $(this.hash);
         target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
         if (target.length) {
           $('html,body').animate({
             scrollTop: target.offset().top - 100
           }, 1000);
           return false;
         }
       }
     });
   });
   ```

---

Here is what your HTML would look like if you were to use the jQuery file that I've just mentioned.

```html
<script async="" src="js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>

  <video preload="auto" autoplay="" loop="" muted="">
 <source src="http://navademo.com/akva-group/uploads/videos/page_2_loop.ogv">
  </video>
```

Shouldn't set the properties or style media directly onto HTML. You need CSS at this point.

```
  background: url(../images/terminal.jpg)
  no-repeat center center fixed;
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1. Find jquery libraries that will do what you expect to see happen on the screen.**

The jQuery files can be found here: https://github.com/VodkaBears/Vide

Just clone and install.  Once you have that done then you simply just put the video, images, and jQuery files in whatever path you choose.  Just make sure you specify the correct paths when writing the syntax and you should have a working site with a video looping in the background without any hiccups.

**Step 2. Edit the CSS file so it doesn't conflict with any text you're trying to place on the graphic if you plan to do so**

Now, since you are defining the parameters of the video files in the HTML (only way I've seen this done without any problem), there isn't actually much to do with the CSS file.  But you do have to define it if you are going to place any text over the video.  This gives the text a reference point of where to be placed even though you can't see the background.

```css
#home {
    background:url("") no-repeat center center fixed;
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')
</script>
<script src="js/jquery.vide.js"></script>

<div id=                "block2"
     style=             "width: 100%; height: 100%;"

     data-vide-bg=      "mp4: path/to/file, 
                         webm: path/to/file, 
                         ogv: path/to/file, 
                         poster: path/to/file" 

     data-vide-options= "position: 0% 100%">
</div>
```